# Why is this jni error occuring when running a jar file, packaged by sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a project that runs fine inside the IDE, but for some reason I can't run the packaged jar from the command line.

This is what my `build.sbt` looks like:

```
import sbt.io.Using

name := "bigdata-mx-2"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.12.7"

libraryDependencies ++=Seq(
  "junit" % "junit" % "4.10" % Test,
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.2.0-SNAP10" % Test,
  "org.apache.parquet" % "parquet-avro" % "1.10.0",
  "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-common" % "3.1.1"
)

packageOptions in (Compile, packageBin) +=  {
  val file = new java.io.File("META-INF/MANIFEST.MF")
  val manifest = Using.fileInputStream(file)( in => new java.util.jar.Manifest(in) )
  Package.JarManifest( manifest )
}
```

I do `sbt compile, package` and get a jar file. when I run it by doing `java -jar myjar.jar`I get:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Function0
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Function0
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 7 more
```

Why is this happenig and how can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Seems like the Scala framework is not being packaged in your jar and not available in the Java classpath.

Comment: @MikePark I started digging in that direction by building a fat jar, but I have a problem, there are duplicated dependencies that I have no idea how to exclude, I have to use assemblyMergeStrategy for this, apparently, but I have no idea where to put it, I asked a question about this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53068110/where-do-you-put-assemblymergestrategy-in-build-sbt

Comment: Why are you trying to create your own JAR manifest? Are you using an _SBT_ plugin to create your fat JAR? If so, you likely don't need to be doing this. Have you seen the _[sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly)_ plugin?

Comment: @MikeAllen yes, I have, I am trying to use it now, but it fails, I describe it here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53068110/where-do-you-put-assemblymergestrategy-in-build-sbt