# Where do you put assemblyMergeStrategy in build.sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly

I have a [MergeStrategy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SfHj.png) problem. How do I resolve it? Why are all those squiggly lines there?

The error message is `Type mismatch, expected: String => MergeStrategy, actual: String => Any`

I am new to scala, so, I have no idea what that syntax means. I have tried copying different merge strategies from all over stackoverflow and none and them work.

I have scala version 2.12.7 and sbt version 1.2.6.

My build.sbt looks like this:

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  settings(
    name := "bigdata-mx-2",
    version := "0.1",
    scalaVersion := "2.12.7",
    mainClass in Compile := Some("Main")
  )

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-core" % "1.2.1",
  "org.apache.parquet" % "parquet-hadoop" % "1.10.0",
  "junit" % "junit" % "4.12" % Test,
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.2.0-SNAP10" % Test,
  "org.scalacheck" %% "scalacheck" % "1.14.0" % Test,
  "org.scala-lang" % "scala-library" % "2.12.7"
)

// Where do I put this thing:
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
  case x => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

Maybe I'm not putting it into the right place, where does it go?

Comment: Did you add assembly plugin? https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly

Comment: Yep. I don't understand what I'm supposed to write in the "PathList(....)" now. The MergeStrategy problem I have resolved...

Comment: TBH, I would only specify a _merge strategy_ if you have errors related to the merging of different JAR file manifests when you create the fat JAR. Have you tried `sbt assembly` without a merge strategy?

Comment: Also, the _[sbt-native-packager](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager)_ plugin might be an alternative for you. It creates installers for various platforms, so you don't have to worry about creating fat JAR files (which can have copyright/distribution issues). The installer installs all of the JAR files your project requires, without merging them together. You might need other tools installed (such as the _[WiXToolset](http://wixtoolset.org/)_ on _Windows_).

Comment: @MikeAllen thank you very much, I just tried sbt-native-packager, and it's awesome!

Comment: I'm glad you like it! Have fun!

Comment: @MikeAllen do you know how to deploy the zip that I packaged with `sbt universal:packageBin`? It seems to be deploying only the javadoc.jar, the sources.jar, .pom and .jar, but not .zip

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand you. What files are packaged up inside the zip file?

Comment: @MikeAllen the jar file with the scala program that I wrote and its dependencies

Comment: OK. To be honest, deploying via zip file isn't that straightforward. What platform are you using/targetting?

Comment: @MikeAllen, I can't verify this right now, but I found this https://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/recipes/deployment.html so I just gotta `enablePlugins(UniversalDeployPlugin)` and do `sbt universal:publish`

Comment: Unzip the file somewhere appropriate (say into `/opt` on _Linux_ or `C:\Program Files` on _Windows_). Then add the extracted `\bin` directory (e.g. `/opt/myprogram/bin` or `C:\Program Files\myprogra\bin`) to your `PATH`. The latter step would be by editing `/etc/environment` on _Linux_, or by adding to your path in the enviroment in the `System` applet (via the _Control Panel_) on _Windows_. For best results, reboot. You should then be able to run your command by typing its named in a _Bash_ or _Command Prompt_ window.

Comment: Or use the universal deploy plugin, of course! Good luck!